# Best Disk Partitioning for OpenBSD with Gnome

Tags: hard-disk, openbsd, whole-drive-encryption

I have a Dell Studio 1555 Laptop with a 320GB Hard Drive. I would like to use it at home for daily stuff. I want to try some video and sound programs for video and sound editing.

I want to try an encrypted OpenBSD, 6.1 OS. Also wish to have "boot" and "swap" folders.

Any suggestions for Hard Drive partitioning?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "boot and swap folders". These don't usually exist on an OpenBSD system. Also, are you asking about what partition sizes to use, or about how to _do_ partitioning with encryption?

Comment: Actually I am new to OpenBSD. So you mean no need for swap at all ? Yes I mean both. Folder Sizes like 'home, root etc. " and encryption offers. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody will be able to tell you the "best" disk partitioning an any system. It will differ depending on use, personal taste and available resources.  I have added my usual setup below, but I'm running headless (and a few and disk-less) systems that I SSH into.

In general, for the *base* system, you only *need* 1 to 2 gigabytes of disk (not including swap). Anything installed from packages will need extra in `/usr/local` and you may want to have extra for `/home` as well.

---

OpenBSD's installer [suggests a default partition scheme](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#Install) that you may want to try first. If you find that some partitions are too small you may choose to reinstall or to [grow the partition](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#GrowPartition) if there is free space to do so.

As with any Unix system, it may take a bit of trial and error to get the sizes right, but if you have experiences from Linux, these may inform your choice of partition sizes as a starting point.

I wouldn't suggest trying a [full-disk encryption setup](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#softraid) on your first install.

In general, when getting to know a new operating system, you may want to play around with it in a virtual environment first.  OpenBSD 6.1 runs without problems in VirtualBox, for example (but it won't do X Windows very well, resolution-wise, as there are no guest additions for VirtualBox on OpenBSD).

Do have a look at [the OpenBSD FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/index.html) on-line. It has information on the specific things you've been asking about.

---

I tend to use separate partitions for `/` (1.5Gb, the *complete* base system needs about 700Mb), `/usr/local` (where `pkg_add` puts packages, usually 20Gb but I don't use big packages) and `/home`. On database servers I allocate as much space as I think I need for `/var` as well, where data is commonly stored. On file-servers that serve NFS shares, I allocate `/export` with as much as I think I need to hold whatever it is I need to serve.  The systems I do my day-to-day work on seldom uses more than a total of 50Gb of disk, but, as I said, I don't use huge packages or store vasts amount of data locally.

---

A clarification on the "swap and boot" folders;  OpenBSD doesn't use `/boot` but like most other Unices it will use a swap *partititon*.  It may also be made to swap to one or several files.

Comment: Actually, I installed it once and In default partition scheme it gives me 1gb space that when I install the gnome and gnome extra packages it says no space available in /root partition.

Comment: @BavêŞêrko All packages are installed under `/usr/local` (except for configuration files etc.), so make sure that partition has enough space.  How much is enough? Nobody can tell you.